# Python ElementTree find() not matching within kml file

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm trying to find an element from a kml file using element trees as follows:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse("history-03-02-2012.kml")
p = tree.find(".//name")
```

A sufficient subset of the file to demonstrate the problem follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>Location history from 03/03/2012 to 03/10/2012</name>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

A "name" element exists; why does the search come back empty?

Comment: In addition to @CharlesDuffy good answer (+1), you can also just change your xpath to `//*[name()='name']`.

Comment: @DevNull ...as an aside -- ElementTree's `find()` is not *quite* XPath; think of it more as a language "inspired by" XPath. As such, while your string is completely valid XPath, and a convenient approach to use with other tools, it doesn't appear to work in the subset xml.etree.ElementTree implements (as opposed to lxml.etree, which uses libxml2's XPath 1.0 implementation).

Comment: You're not using LXML. You're using Python's built-in ETree implementation. Do `from lxml import etree` to get LXML's expanded one.

Comment: @larsmans the lxml reference in the question was actually bad editing on my part -- looks like I backed it out at about the same time you added your comment. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `name` element you're trying to match is actually within the KML namespace, but you aren't searching with that namespace in mind.

Try:

```
p = tree.find(".//{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}name")
```

If you were using lxml's XPath instead of the standard-library ElementTree, you'd instead pass the namespace in as a dictionary:

```
>>> tree = lxml.etree.fromstring('''<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
...   <Document>
...     <name>Location history from 03/03/2012 to 03/10/2012</name>
...   </Document>
... </kml>''')
>>> tree.xpath('//kml:name', namespaces={'kml': "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"})
[<Element {http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}name at 0x23afe60>]
```