# Remove KML 'name' tags using Python26

Tags: xml, replace, tags, kml, elementtree

My research found that using XPath and/or xml ElementTree should work, but with the following code (I know it needs some work - new to python), I cannot yield the result I'm looking for.

I'm looking to replace any name tag in my kml, that exceeds a single character, to a blank string. I would like to keep the structure of the element tree as there are important folders and subfolders, so a line by line string.replace method may not work because of unknown  indentation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, here is what I have so far.

```
import sys, string, os, lxml
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

kml_file = open(r'C:\temp\doc.kml', 'r')

tree = ET.parse(kml_file)
root = tree.getroot()
for name in root.findall('.//{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}name'):
    if len(name.text) > 1:
        name.text = ""

kml_file.close()
```

Sample KML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>TempFile.kmz</name>
    <open>1</open>
    <StyleMap id="msn_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#sn_ylw-pushpin3</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#sh_ylw-pushpin0</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="sn_ylw-pushpin3">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="sh_ylw-pushpin0">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Folder>
        <name>My Places</name>
        <open>1</open>
        <Style>
            <ListStyle>
                <listItemType>check</listItemType>
                <ItemIcon>
                    <state>open</state>
                    <href>C:/Documents and Settings/sfmeyer/Local Settings/Temp/wz5b57/files/mysavedplaces_open.png</href>
                </ItemIcon>
                <ItemIcon>
                    <state>closed</state>
                    <href>C:/Documents and Settings/sfmeyer/Local Settings/Temp/wz5b57/files/mysavedplaces_closed.png</href>
                </ItemIcon>
                <bgColor>00ffffff</bgColor>
                <maxSnippetLines>2</maxSnippetLines>
            </ListStyle>
        </Style>
        <Placemark>
            <name>NameRemove0</name>
            <LookAt>
                <longitude>-111.6385075333604</longitude>
                <latitude>33.89355748553</latitude>
                <altitude>0</altitude>
                <heading>-0.003511129776839782</heading>
                <tilt>18.73370091942461</tilt>
                <range>363.2207262112541</range>
                <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
            </LookAt>
            <styleUrl>#msn_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <gx:altitudeMode>clampToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
                <coordinates>-111.6380073829088,33.89304257965345,0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Error:

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 862, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 587, in parse
    self._root = parser.close()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python26\ArcGIS10.0\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1254, in close
    self._parser.Parse("", 1) # end of data
ExpatError: unclosed CDATA section: line 286, column 77
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing your KML file, I can't say for certain that this is your problem, but more than likely 'name' probably doesn't appear outside your KML namespace.  Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639786/) for more details and how to do it in [lxml](http://lxml.de/).

In regular ElementTree syntax, if the contents of doc.kml were -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
    <name>KML Samples</name>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

you could use:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

kml_file = open(r'C:\temp\doc.kml, 'r')

tree = ET.parse(kml_file)
root = tree.getroot()
for name in root.findall('.//{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}name'):
    if len(name.text) > 1:
        name.text = ""

kml_file.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and sample. Using the code block you have provided, I am returning an error. I have edited my original comment with both my sample KML and the error message. Would you have any ideas of why this would occur? Many thanks.

Comment: @S.Meyer - The parser is failing for me as well because the sample KML file you posted is not valid XML.  Try [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp).

Comment: Voting you up as soon as I get enough reputation. Your kind and generous assistance is much appreciated. I originally only shared an exert of the code, I have edited my source KML code to reflect a valid XML doc. However, after the python script runs, with no errors, the KML names remain the same, and no change is detected? Am I missing something else? Again, many thanks.

Comment: Ok, simple enough. The script required some minor modifications. See final script below. Thank you very much @pauldom.

Comment: @S.Meyer -  Are you trying to modify the names within the file itself?  The python operators only work on the file within the buffer, the original file will remain unchanged.  If you want to see the changes you have to write them to a new file or overwrite the old file with the contents of the buffer

Comment: @S.Meyer- Ok, I just saw that you did that already.  If the answer worked for you, don't forget to accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the original script, I added a variable with an output name, and a function to write the new file at the end. 
The "Error:" section of my original post was due to invalid formatting within the KML document, which @pauldom pointed out because I only shared an exert of the entire doc.

```
import sys, string, os, lxml
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

kml_file = open(r'C:\temp\doc.kml', 'r+')
kml_file2 = (r'C:\temp\doc2.kml')

tree = ET.parse(kml_file)
root = tree.getroot()
for name in root.findall('.//{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}name'):
    if len(name.text) > 1:
        name.text = "n/a"
        tree.write(kml_file2)                
kml_file.close()
```